# Rails inadvertently showing JSON in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using Rails 4 and have a weird issue in one of my views. In my controller I'm getting a weather feed from OpenWeatherMap.org using the [Ruby_Open_Weather_Map](https://github.com/coderhs/ruby_open_weather_map) gem. The data is returned as JSON and I am looping through the JSON and extracting the forcast information for the next 5 days. What's weird is that after my loop, the JSON data is displayed.

[image]

I'm new to Rails and to JSON and this doesn't make any sense to me. I have a second page that has even more information on it and the same thing happens. This is what my controller looks like:

```
  def index
    options = { units: "Imperial", APPID: '6eff99d4b460d3a1acddcf1a727a7a45' }
    @currentweather = OpenWeather::Current.city("Greenville, SC", options)
    @forcastweather = OpenWeather::ForecastDaily.city("Greenville, SC", options)
  end
```

and this is what my view looks like:

```
    <%= @forcastweather['list'].each do | day | %>
    <div class ="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <strong><%= Time.at(DateTime.strptime(day['dt'].to_s,'%s')).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime("%A") %></strong>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <%= day['temp']['min'] %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <%= day['temp']['max'] %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/<%= day['weather'][0]['icon'] %>.png" alt="<%= day['weather'][0]['main'].humanize %>">
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Why is the JSON displaying in my view and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= @forcastweather['list'].each do | day | %>
```

Take the = out

```
<% @forcastweather['list'].each do | day | %>
```

Using `<%=` will tell rails to evaluate this code, then render the outcome, so rails evaluates the code, loops the entries, writes the html... then renders the value of `@forcastweather['list']`.

`<%` will tell rails to evaluate the code, but not render anything from it.

Comment: Glad I could help @mack, please accept the answer to close the question!